# PHP: System program execution

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I'm using Joomla 3 as CMS and when I make a system check for a plugin, I get the following warning:

```
System Command Warning
System program execution should be enabled.
```

Can someone tell me how to enable that? Unfortunately I have no clue about PHP and can't see an option to enable this in my backend.

Comment: System check for a plugin? You mean Discover?

Comment: [Program execution functions in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php) might be disabled by your web hoster as it is a source of security holes. Check that with your hosting provider